# AUC-ROC value greater than 1 for XGBoost classifier

Tags: python, classification, xgboost, imbalanced-data

I am training a classifier for an imbalanced dataset. In the logs below one can see that the trainingset-auc increases over 1 after the 78th booster is added. What could AUC-ROC value greater than 1 signify? Since the area under the curve is not expected to be greater than 1 could there be something wrong with my oversampled data which is causing this issue? For this training I am using auc-pr as a metric for evaluation to output the best iteration.

I am using the python XGBoost library for this. The hyperparams being used here were tuned for an older version of the same model. Is hyperparam retuning for this version recommended to resolve this?

```
param = {
         'eta':0.05, 
         'subsample':0.5, 
         'colsample_bytree': 0.9387046046168422,
         'gamma': 4.533133064606544,
         'max_depth': 6.167312302144592,
         'min_child_weight': 5.369834798013086
}

param['eval_metric']=['auc','aucpr']
param['objective']='binary:logistic'
param['nthread']=6
param['max_depth']=int(param['max_depth'])
watchlist  = [(dtrain,'trainingset'), (dtest,'evalualtionset')]

bst = xgb.train(param, dtrain, num_round_opt, watchlist,early_stopping_rounds=10, maximize=True)
```

```
[0] trainingset-auc:0.97164 trainingset-aucpr:0.98648   evalualtionset-auc:0.96008  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.65317
[1] trainingset-auc:0.97540 trainingset-aucpr:0.98780   evalualtionset-auc:0.96368  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.67202
[2] trainingset-auc:0.97850 trainingset-aucpr:0.99092   evalualtionset-auc:0.96786  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.71809
[3] trainingset-auc:0.97884 trainingset-aucpr:0.99107   evalualtionset-auc:0.96856  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.72405
[4] trainingset-auc:0.98322 trainingset-aucpr:0.99278   evalualtionset-auc:0.97693  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.79977
[5] trainingset-auc:0.98384 trainingset-aucpr:0.99299   evalualtionset-auc:0.97684  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.79582
[6] trainingset-auc:0.98400 trainingset-aucpr:0.99327   evalualtionset-auc:0.97822  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.80698
[7] trainingset-auc:0.98405 trainingset-aucpr:0.99329   evalualtionset-auc:0.97830  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.80772
[8] trainingset-auc:0.98406 trainingset-aucpr:0.99329   evalualtionset-auc:0.97806  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.80557
[9] trainingset-auc:0.98392 trainingset-aucpr:0.99328   evalualtionset-auc:0.97838  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.80744
[10]    trainingset-auc:0.98417 trainingset-aucpr:0.99335   evalualtionset-auc:0.97845  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.80712
[11]    trainingset-auc:0.98423 trainingset-aucpr:0.99337   evalualtionset-auc:0.97835  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.80620
[12]    trainingset-auc:0.98497 trainingset-aucpr:0.99364   evalualtionset-auc:0.97885  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.80868
[13]    trainingset-auc:0.98496 trainingset-aucpr:0.99364   evalualtionset-auc:0.97885  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.80832
[14]    trainingset-auc:0.98585 trainingset-aucpr:0.99380   evalualtionset-auc:0.97940  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.80942
[15]    trainingset-auc:0.98620 trainingset-aucpr:0.99380   evalualtionset-auc:0.98022  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.81149
[16]    trainingset-auc:0.98633 trainingset-aucpr:0.99385   evalualtionset-auc:0.98035  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.81172
[17]    trainingset-auc:0.98660 trainingset-aucpr:0.99393   evalualtionset-auc:0.98026  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.81135
[18]    trainingset-auc:0.98666 trainingset-aucpr:0.99395   evalualtionset-auc:0.98014  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.81041
[19]    trainingset-auc:0.98720 trainingset-aucpr:0.99414   evalualtionset-auc:0.98070  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.81233
[20]    trainingset-auc:0.98726 trainingset-aucpr:0.99418   evalualtionset-auc:0.98115  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.81617
[21]    trainingset-auc:0.98748 trainingset-aucpr:0.99434   evalualtionset-auc:0.98128  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.81832
[22]    trainingset-auc:0.98778 trainingset-aucpr:0.99448   evalualtionset-auc:0.98151  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.82042
[23]    trainingset-auc:0.98787 trainingset-aucpr:0.99451   evalualtionset-auc:0.98158  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.82183
[24]    trainingset-auc:0.98803 trainingset-aucpr:0.99456   evalualtionset-auc:0.98171  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.82221
[25]    trainingset-auc:0.98821 trainingset-aucpr:0.99464   evalualtionset-auc:0.98194  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.82412
[26]    trainingset-auc:0.98836 trainingset-aucpr:0.99459   evalualtionset-auc:0.98231  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.82474
[27]    trainingset-auc:0.98872 trainingset-aucpr:0.99467   evalualtionset-auc:0.98255  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.82629
[28]    trainingset-auc:0.98948 trainingset-aucpr:0.99503   evalualtionset-auc:0.98272  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.82888
[29]    trainingset-auc:0.98964 trainingset-aucpr:0.99510   evalualtionset-auc:0.98270  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.82944
[30]    trainingset-auc:0.98982 trainingset-aucpr:0.99513   evalualtionset-auc:0.98285  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.83007
[31]    trainingset-auc:0.98996 trainingset-aucpr:0.99516   evalualtionset-auc:0.98299  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.83081
[32]    trainingset-auc:0.99007 trainingset-aucpr:0.99518   evalualtionset-auc:0.98307  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.83084
[33]    trainingset-auc:0.99016 trainingset-aucpr:0.99520   evalualtionset-auc:0.98322  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.83247
[34]    trainingset-auc:0.99044 trainingset-aucpr:0.99526   evalualtionset-auc:0.98339  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.83269
[35]    trainingset-auc:0.99055 trainingset-aucpr:0.99530   evalualtionset-auc:0.98356  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.83398
[36]    trainingset-auc:0.99069 trainingset-aucpr:0.99534   evalualtionset-auc:0.98371  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.83408
[37]    trainingset-auc:0.99082 trainingset-aucpr:0.99542   evalualtionset-auc:0.98383  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.83512
[38]    trainingset-auc:0.99143 trainingset-aucpr:0.99562   evalualtionset-auc:0.98401  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.83669
[39]    trainingset-auc:0.99149 trainingset-aucpr:0.99565   evalualtionset-auc:0.98410  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.83738
[40]    trainingset-auc:0.99178 trainingset-aucpr:0.99572   evalualtionset-auc:0.98423  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.83810
[41]    trainingset-auc:0.99228 trainingset-aucpr:0.99579   evalualtionset-auc:0.98449  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.83873
[42]    trainingset-auc:0.99235 trainingset-aucpr:0.99582   evalualtionset-auc:0.98461  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.83915
[43]    trainingset-auc:0.99250 trainingset-aucpr:0.99585   evalualtionset-auc:0.98470  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.83996
[44]    trainingset-auc:0.99277 trainingset-aucpr:0.99593   evalualtionset-auc:0.98486  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.84172
[45]    trainingset-auc:0.99284 trainingset-aucpr:0.99595   evalualtionset-auc:0.98501  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.84308
[46]    trainingset-auc:0.99306 trainingset-aucpr:0.99602   evalualtionset-auc:0.98517  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.84485
[47]    trainingset-auc:0.99330 trainingset-aucpr:0.99608   evalualtionset-auc:0.98522  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.84564
[48]    trainingset-auc:0.99348 trainingset-aucpr:0.99611   evalualtionset-auc:0.98520  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.84604
[49]    trainingset-auc:0.99359 trainingset-aucpr:0.99612   evalualtionset-auc:0.98533  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.84591
[50]    trainingset-auc:0.99370 trainingset-aucpr:0.99616   evalualtionset-auc:0.98534  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.84641
[51]    trainingset-auc:0.99389 trainingset-aucpr:0.99621   evalualtionset-auc:0.98532  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.84722
[52]    trainingset-auc:0.99406 trainingset-aucpr:0.99625   evalualtionset-auc:0.98531  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.84768
[53]    trainingset-auc:0.99418 trainingset-aucpr:0.99629   evalualtionset-auc:0.98536  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.84730
[54]    trainingset-auc:0.99431 trainingset-aucpr:0.99631   evalualtionset-auc:0.98540  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.84793
[55]    trainingset-auc:0.99447 trainingset-aucpr:0.99635   evalualtionset-auc:0.98537  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.84761
[56]    trainingset-auc:0.99468 trainingset-aucpr:0.99639   evalualtionset-auc:0.98535  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.84717
[57]    trainingset-auc:0.99501 trainingset-aucpr:0.99644   evalualtionset-auc:0.98553  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.84739
[58]    trainingset-auc:0.99513 trainingset-aucpr:0.99646   evalualtionset-auc:0.98559  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.84769
[59]    trainingset-auc:0.99541 trainingset-aucpr:0.99648   evalualtionset-auc:0.98569  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.84786
[60]    trainingset-auc:0.99556 trainingset-aucpr:0.99650   evalualtionset-auc:0.98570  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.84787
[61]    trainingset-auc:0.99587 trainingset-aucpr:0.99655   evalualtionset-auc:0.98580  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.84833
[62]    trainingset-auc:0.99604 trainingset-aucpr:0.99657   evalualtionset-auc:0.98585  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.84825
[63]    trainingset-auc:0.99636 trainingset-aucpr:0.99659   evalualtionset-auc:0.98586  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.84789
[64]    trainingset-auc:0.99656 trainingset-aucpr:0.99662   evalualtionset-auc:0.98599  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.84885
[65]    trainingset-auc:0.99668 trainingset-aucpr:0.99664   evalualtionset-auc:0.98601  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.84901
[66]    trainingset-auc:0.99678 trainingset-aucpr:0.99665   evalualtionset-auc:0.98604  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.84928
[67]    trainingset-auc:0.99696 trainingset-aucpr:0.99666   evalualtionset-auc:0.98606  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.84882
[68]    trainingset-auc:0.99711 trainingset-aucpr:0.99668   evalualtionset-auc:0.98611  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.84903
[69]    trainingset-auc:0.99740 trainingset-aucpr:0.99672   evalualtionset-auc:0.98619  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.84895
[70]    trainingset-auc:0.99751 trainingset-aucpr:0.99674   evalualtionset-auc:0.98615  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.84869
[71]    trainingset-auc:0.99783 trainingset-aucpr:0.99679   evalualtionset-auc:0.98622  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.84856
[72]    trainingset-auc:0.99815 trainingset-aucpr:0.99682   evalualtionset-auc:0.98628  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.84832
[73]    trainingset-auc:0.99838 trainingset-aucpr:0.99687   evalualtionset-auc:0.98628  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.84822
[74]    trainingset-auc:0.99875 trainingset-aucpr:0.99690   evalualtionset-auc:0.98640  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.84883
[75]    trainingset-auc:0.99884 trainingset-aucpr:0.99691   evalualtionset-auc:0.98646  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.84923
[76]    trainingset-auc:0.99900 trainingset-aucpr:0.99692   evalualtionset-auc:0.98646  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.84933
[77]    trainingset-auc:0.99951 trainingset-aucpr:0.99695   evalualtionset-auc:0.98674  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.84985
[78]    trainingset-auc:1.00024 trainingset-aucpr:0.99699   evalualtionset-auc:0.98697  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.84964
[79]    trainingset-auc:1.00058 trainingset-aucpr:0.99700   evalualtionset-auc:0.98719  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.84987
[80]    trainingset-auc:1.00090 trainingset-aucpr:0.99702   evalualtionset-auc:0.98727  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.84965
[81]    trainingset-auc:1.00111 trainingset-aucpr:0.99706   evalualtionset-auc:0.98733  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.85003
[82]    trainingset-auc:1.00129 trainingset-aucpr:0.99710   evalualtionset-auc:0.98741  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.85001
[83]    trainingset-auc:1.00143 trainingset-aucpr:0.99711   evalualtionset-auc:0.98744  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.85045
[84]    trainingset-auc:1.00161 trainingset-aucpr:0.99716   evalualtionset-auc:0.98743  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.85045
[85]    trainingset-auc:1.00235 trainingset-aucpr:0.99721   evalualtionset-auc:0.98778  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.85076
[86]    trainingset-auc:1.00266 trainingset-aucpr:0.99724   evalualtionset-auc:0.98788  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.85038
[87]    trainingset-auc:1.00302 trainingset-aucpr:0.99725   evalualtionset-auc:0.98803  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.85063
[88]    trainingset-auc:1.00341 trainingset-aucpr:0.99729   evalualtionset-auc:0.98837  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.85198
[89]    trainingset-auc:1.00393 trainingset-aucpr:0.99731   evalualtionset-auc:0.98868  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.85253
[90]    trainingset-auc:1.00445 trainingset-aucpr:0.99732   evalualtionset-auc:0.98889  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.85306
[91]    trainingset-auc:1.00450 trainingset-aucpr:0.99735   evalualtionset-auc:0.98897  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.85393
[92]    trainingset-auc:1.00561 trainingset-aucpr:0.99737   evalualtionset-auc:0.98945  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.85371
[93]    trainingset-auc:1.00588 trainingset-aucpr:0.99738   evalualtionset-auc:0.98951  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.85383
[94]    trainingset-auc:1.00602 trainingset-aucpr:0.99739   evalualtionset-auc:0.98959  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.85399
[95]    trainingset-auc:1.00644 trainingset-aucpr:0.99741   evalualtionset-auc:0.98996  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.85467
[96]    trainingset-auc:1.00653 trainingset-aucpr:0.99742   evalualtionset-auc:0.98993  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.85481
[97]    trainingset-auc:1.00665 trainingset-aucpr:0.99744   evalualtionset-auc:0.99003  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.85595
[98]    trainingset-auc:1.00708 trainingset-aucpr:0.99747   evalualtionset-auc:0.99050  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.85680
[99]    trainingset-auc:1.00771 trainingset-aucpr:0.99747   evalualtionset-auc:0.99068  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.85696
[100]   trainingset-auc:1.00809 trainingset-aucpr:0.99749   evalualtionset-auc:0.99089  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.85706
[101]   trainingset-auc:1.00842 trainingset-aucpr:0.99751   evalualtionset-auc:0.99103  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.85717
[102]   trainingset-auc:1.00890 trainingset-aucpr:0.99753   evalualtionset-auc:0.99124  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.85699
[103]   trainingset-auc:1.00901 trainingset-aucpr:0.99753   evalualtionset-auc:0.99127  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.85706
[104]   trainingset-auc:1.00912 trainingset-aucpr:0.99755   evalualtionset-auc:0.99134  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.85719
[105]   trainingset-auc:1.00919 trainingset-aucpr:0.99757   evalualtionset-auc:0.99130  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.85749
[106]   trainingset-auc:1.00960 trainingset-aucpr:0.99759   evalualtionset-auc:0.99147  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.85720
[107]   trainingset-auc:1.01100 trainingset-aucpr:0.99760   evalualtionset-auc:0.99188  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.85763
[108]   trainingset-auc:1.01279 trainingset-aucpr:0.99762   evalualtionset-auc:0.99284  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.85757
[109]   trainingset-auc:1.01298 trainingset-aucpr:0.99763   evalualtionset-auc:0.99288  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.85746
[110]   trainingset-auc:1.01380 trainingset-aucpr:0.99765   evalualtionset-auc:0.99343  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.85782
[111]   trainingset-auc:1.01421 trainingset-aucpr:0.99765   evalualtionset-auc:0.99352  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.85784
[112]   trainingset-auc:1.01439 trainingset-aucpr:0.99767   evalualtionset-auc:0.99359  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.85771
[113]   trainingset-auc:1.01446 trainingset-aucpr:0.99768   evalualtionset-auc:0.99367  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.85838
[114]   trainingset-auc:1.01457 trainingset-aucpr:0.99769   evalualtionset-auc:0.99372  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.85821
[115]   trainingset-auc:1.01500 trainingset-aucpr:0.99770   evalualtionset-auc:0.99406  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.85837
[116]   trainingset-auc:1.01590 trainingset-aucpr:0.99771   evalualtionset-auc:0.99432  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.85814
[117]   trainingset-auc:1.01639 trainingset-aucpr:0.99772   evalualtionset-auc:0.99467  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.85830
[118]   trainingset-auc:1.01688 trainingset-aucpr:0.99773   evalualtionset-auc:0.99487  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.85819
[119]   trainingset-auc:1.01817 trainingset-aucpr:0.99775   evalualtionset-auc:0.99528  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.85877
[120]   trainingset-auc:1.01843 trainingset-aucpr:0.99776   evalualtionset-auc:0.99534  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.85879
[121]   trainingset-auc:1.01848 trainingset-aucpr:0.99777   evalualtionset-auc:0.99536  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.85867
[122]   trainingset-auc:1.01858 trainingset-aucpr:0.99777   evalualtionset-auc:0.99538  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.85854
[123]   trainingset-auc:1.01896 trainingset-aucpr:0.99778   evalualtionset-auc:0.99546  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.85856
[124]   trainingset-auc:1.01913 trainingset-aucpr:0.99779   evalualtionset-auc:0.99560  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.85925
[125]   trainingset-auc:1.01920 trainingset-aucpr:0.99779   evalualtionset-auc:0.99561  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.85938
[126]   trainingset-auc:1.01927 trainingset-aucpr:0.99781   evalualtionset-auc:0.99572  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.86009
[127]   trainingset-auc:1.01976 trainingset-aucpr:0.99782   evalualtionset-auc:0.99592  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.86018
[128]   trainingset-auc:1.01990 trainingset-aucpr:0.99782   evalualtionset-auc:0.99596  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.86008
[129]   trainingset-auc:1.02059 trainingset-aucpr:0.99784   evalualtionset-auc:0.99628  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.86020
[130]   trainingset-auc:1.02077 trainingset-aucpr:0.99784   evalualtionset-auc:0.99634  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.86014
[131]   trainingset-auc:1.02081 trainingset-aucpr:0.99785   evalualtionset-auc:0.99641  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.86084
[132]   trainingset-auc:1.02129 trainingset-aucpr:0.99787   evalualtionset-auc:0.99677  evalualtionset-aucpr:0.86086
```